# Currency in Pandas Styler (rs)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, pandas-styles

Want to pandas style Currency : Rupee \u20B9  ([How to print currency symbol and an n-digit decimal number right aligned in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875517/how-to-print-currency-symbol-and-an-n-digit-decimal-number-right-aligned-in-pyth))

```
format_dict = {'Premium Per Rep':'{0:,.0f}'}
f1=f.style.background_gradient().format(format_dict)
```

However, getting the below (works for $)

[image: Bad Format]

Answer (score 0):

Need to define the format spec correctly:

```
df.style.format('\u20B9{:,.0f}')
```